# Create a trigger that updates another table when a new item is inserted

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table rating(idrating,clientno,spid,rating) and serviceprovider(spid,name,totalrating).

I want to create a trigger such that it avg all the rating of the spid and put it in the totalrating column. What's the best way to do so? or is it impossible for a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT_TOTAL` AFTER INSERT ON `rating`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO serviceprovider( spid, name, totalrating ) 
VALUES (

NEW.spid,  'name', (

SELECT AVG( spid ) 
FROM rating
)
)
```

With update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT_TOTAL` AFTER INSERT ON  `rating` 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE serviceprovider SET totalrating = ( SELECT AVG( spid ) FROM rating ) 
WHERE name =  'name'
```

Comment: It says an error in line 4

`CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_TOTAL AFTER INSERT ON rating
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO serviceprovider (spid,first_name,last_name,email,contactno,username,password,accepted,totalrating,profpic) VALUES (NEW.spid, (SELECT AVG(spid) FROM rating)) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4`

Comment: I have tested it and it kinda works but what it does is make a new serviceprovider instead of just update the certain service provider.

Comment: You mean you want to update a column in the same table where you inserted?

Comment: I edited again with update. Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Thank you. It now works fine. It alse helped me understand triggers XD
I adjusted it a bit also `TRIGGER `INSERT_TOTAL` AFTER INSERT ON `ratings`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE serviceproviders SET totalrating = ( SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings WHERE spid =  NEW.spid group by spid) 
WHERE serviceproviders.spid =  NEW.spid`